# RecyclerView uses wrong values

Tags: android

So, I use a RecyclerView for displaying a grid. In the onBindViewHolder method of its adapter I update the view content. I put a part of the update into another thread to keep the UI alive.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder (final MovieHolder holder, final int position) {
    // Blah, blah. Set movie details. Everything is fine.

    // Generate a palette or load from the memory and adjust the background color of the view.
     new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run () {
            Palette palette = getPalette();
            final Palette.Swatch bestSwatch = findBestSwatch(palette)                

            if (bestSwatch != null) {
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       holder.layout.setBackgroundColor(bestSwatch.getRgb());
                   }
                ));
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

It works well, except when no bestSwatch was found. Then for the first time, it displays a correct background color and when I scroll down and back it will have a random color from one of the views.

Why does RecyclerView changes the color of my view when I don't update it?

Comment: Did you ever wonder why recyclerview has its name... that why it happens... And lack of else... Also for the same reason it will not work good when some pallete calculations takes more time then other and you fast scroll up and down...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RecyclerView` reuses its rows, the `ViewHolder`s, hence its name. So your problem is that a recycled view has the background color it was set to at another recent position.
Solution to this is simple...

```
Palette.from(bitmap).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {

            Palette.Swatch swatch = palette.getDarkVibrantSwatch();

            if (swatch == null)
                swatch = new Palette.Swatch(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.fallback_background), 4);

            holder.layout.setBackgroundColor(swatch.getRgb());
        }
    });
```

So, you always set a BackgroundColor. When there's no swatch generated, you create one using a fallback layout background color you define at `colors.xml`

Comment: Wow. I didn't know about that. I thought it is RecyclerView, because views are cached or something similar. Next time I will study for a longer time, before trying to use a new thing. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: There will still some problems with this code... Which comes also from recycling... Start pallete calculations for example it takes 2 s now same view is reused and starts another calculation which takes 1s... Right pallete calculate faster and is set then old calculation is finished and set wrong background... It not be appear always but there is a chance for such behaviour...

Comment: How? Because that has never happened in my apps. The `ViewHolder` instance passed is `final`.

Comment: It doesn't matter... The point is that generate is an ansync method... And there is a chance that it will be done for the same holder at the same time if holder is reused... as i wrote it may not appear always nor even at all... But there is a chance... To avoid this it would be good to store hash of bitmap in holder and in some final variable and if they are not equal do not set the background... Same things are done in image loaders